# nbsp unicode xA0 gets printed in XML resulting in error

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I have a utility that converts Java object into XML. Below is an output snippet. As can be seen, the unicode character xA0 gets added for non breaking space. Obviously this does not get processed and results in error.Also, this occurs whenever there are multiple consecutive spaces and the second space gets replaced by this character. For me that looks like a bug in the utility, but my question is - what could cause this on the first place? Assuming utility encodes xml in UTF-8, why do the editors (tried notepad++, gvim) do not recognize the second space (searching using ATTN followed by space results in match, however ATTN followed by two spaces does not match).

[image]

Comment: Please show us some code, or there's nothing to be done. Also the image is completely illegible.

Comment: Is this character `U+00A0` or byte `A0`? Also, post the code.